# SSL certificates not being verified on client side

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have a simple client-server program in C, using the OpenSSL library, where I am establishing a TCP connection between the 2, followed by an SSL handshake. The client and server programs are as follows :-

**Server**

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include "openssl/ssl.h"
#include "openssl/err.h"

#define FAIL    -1
#define SERVER_CERTIFICATE "./certs/cert.pem"
#define SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY "./certs/key.pem"
#define CA_CERTIFICATE "../caroot/cert.pem"

int OpenListener(int port) {
    int sd;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    
    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    
    if (bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 ) {
        perror("can't bind port");
        printf("Cannot bind port\n");
        abort();
    }
    else  printf("Port bind Succesful\n");

    if (listen(sd, 10) != 0 ) {
        perror("Can't configure listening port");
        abort();
    }
    else printf("Configured listening port\n");

    return sd;
}


int isRoot() {
    if (getuid() != 0) return 0;
    else return 1;
}

int ssl_verify_callback_initial(int status, X509_STORE_CTX* store_ctx) {
    if(status == 0) 
    {
        printf("Verification failed, bad certificate\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Verification success, certificate OK\n");
    }
    return status;
}

void LoadCertificates(SSL_CTX* ctx, char* CertFile, char* KeyFile) {
    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CertFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) 
    {
        // ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        printf("Error loading server certificate\n");
        abort();
    }
    else printf("Server certificate loaded\n");

    if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KeyFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) 
    {
        printf("Error loading server private key\n");
        // ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    else printf("Server private key loaded\n");

    if (!SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx)) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Private key does not match the public certificate\n");
        abort();
    }
}

void addCertificateToStore(X509_STORE *x509_store, SSL_CTX *ctx, char* cert_file) {
    X509 *cacert = NULL;
    
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(cert_file, "r");
    if(fp == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Could not find CA certificate\n");
        abort();
    }

    if(!PEM_read_X509(fp, &cacert, NULL, NULL)) 
    {
        printf("Can't read CA certificate into X509 object\n");
        abort();
    }

    if(SSL_CTX_add_client_CA(ctx, cacert) != 1) 
    {
        printf("Can't add CA certificate to client list\n");
        abort();
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Added CA certificate to client list\n");
    }

    if(X509_STORE_add_cert(x509_store, cacert) != 1) 
    {
        printf("Can't add CA certificate to X509 store\n");
        if(cacert)
        {
            X509_free(cacert);
        }
        X509_STORE_free(x509_store);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Added CA certificate to X509 store\n");
    }
}

SSL_CTX* InitServerCTX(void) {
    SSL_CTX *ctx = NULL;
    X509_STORE *x509_store = NULL;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    const SSL_METHOD *method = TLSv1_2_server_method();
    
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    if ( ctx == NULL ) 
    {
        printf("Unable to create SSL Context\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    else {
        printf("SSL Context Created\n");
    }

    if ( !(x509_store = X509_STORE_new() ) ) 
    {
        printf("Unable to create X509 Store\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("X509 Store created\n");
    }

    addCertificateToStore(x509_store, ctx, CA_CERTIFICATE);    

    SSL_CTX_set_cert_store(ctx, x509_store);
    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, ssl_verify_callback_initial);
    return ctx;
}

void ShowCerts(SSL* ssl) {
    X509 *cert;
    char *line;
    
    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);
    if ( cert != NULL )
    {
        printf("Client certificates:\n");
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Subject: %s\n", line);
        free(line);
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Issuer: %s\n", line);
        free(line);
        X509_free(cert);
    }
    else {
        printf("No certificates.\n");
    }
}

void Servlet(SSL* ssl) {
    char buf[1024] = {0};
    int sd, bytes;

    if (SSL_accept(ssl) == FAIL) 
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }
    else 
    {
        ShowCerts(ssl);
        bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf));
        buf[bytes] = '\0';
        printf("Client msg: \"%s\"\n", buf);
    }
    
    sd = SSL_get_fd(ssl);
    SSL_free(ssl);
    close(sd);
}

int main(int args, char *argv[]) {
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    int server;
    char *portnum;

    if(!isRoot()) {
        printf("This program must be run as root/sudo user!!");
        exit(0);
    }

    if (args != 2 ) {
        printf("Usage: %s <portnum>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }

    portnum = argv[1];
    int port = atoi(portnum);
    server = OpenListener(port);

    SSL_library_init();
    ctx = InitServerCTX();
    LoadCertificates(ctx, SERVER_CERTIFICATE, SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY);

    while(1) 
    {
      struct sockaddr_in addr;
      socklen_t len = sizeof(addr);
      SSL *ssl;
      int client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);
      printf("Connection: %s:%d\n",inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), ntohs(addr.sin_port));
      ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
      SSL_set_fd(ssl, client);
      Servlet(ssl);
    }

    close(server);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    return 0;
}
```

**Client**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#define CLIENT_CERTIFICATE "./certs/cert.pem"
#define CLIENT_PRIVATE_KEY "./certs/key.pem"
#define CA_CERTIFICATE "../caroot/cert.pem"

int OpenConnection(const char *hostname, int port) {
    int sd;
    struct hostent *host;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    if ( (host = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL )
    {
        printf("Could not find host\n");
        perror(hostname);
        abort();
    }
    else 
    {
      printf("Succesfully found host - %s\n", host->h_name);
    }

    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)(host->h_addr);
    
    if ( connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 )
    {
        printf("Connection Failed\n");
        close(sd);
        perror(hostname);
        abort();
    }
    else {
      printf("Connection Succesful at socket %d\n", sd);
    }

    return sd;
}

int ssl_verify_callback_initial(int status, X509_STORE_CTX* store_ctx) {
  if(status == 0) {
    printf("Verification failed\n");
  }
  else {
    printf("Verification success, certificate OK\n");
  }
  return status;
}

void ShowCerts(SSL* ssl) {
    X509 *cert;
    char *line;
    
    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);
    if ( cert != NULL )
    {
      printf("Server certificates:\n");
      line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
      printf("Subject: %s\n", line);
      free(line);
      line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
      printf("Issuer: %s\n", line);
      free(line);
      X509_free(cert);
    }
    else {
      printf("Info: No client certificates configured.\n");
    }
}

SSL_CTX* InitCTX(void) {
    SSL_CTX *ctx = NULL;
    X509_STORE *x509_store = NULL;
    X509 *cacert = NULL;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    const SSL_METHOD * method = TLSv1_2_client_method();
    
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    if ( ctx == NULL )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        printf("Error in creating SSL context\n");
        abort();
    }
    else {
        printf("Successfully created SSL Context\n");
    }

    if ( !(x509_store = X509_STORE_new() ) ) 
    {
        printf("Unable to create X509 Store\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("X509 Store created\n");
    }

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(CA_CERTIFICATE, "r");
    if(fp == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Could not find CA certificate\n");
        abort();
    }

    if(!PEM_read_X509(fp, &cacert, NULL, NULL)) 
    {
        printf("Can't read CA certificate into X509 object\n");
        abort();
    }

    if(X509_STORE_add_cert(x509_store, cacert) != 1) 
    {
        printf("Can't add CA certificate to X509 store\n");
        if(cacert)
        {
            X509_free(cacert);
        }
        X509_STORE_free(x509_store);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Added CA certificate to X509 store\n");
    }
    
    SSL_CTX_set_cert_store(ctx, x509_store);
    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, ssl_verify_callback_initial);
    return ctx;
}

int main(int args, char* argv[]) {
  SSL_CTX *ctx = NULL;
  SSL *ssl = NULL;
  
  char* hostname = argv[1];
  char* port = argv[2];
  int portnum = atoi(port);

  int server;
  server = OpenConnection(hostname, portnum);

  SSL_library_init();
  ctx = InitCTX();
  ssl = SSL_new(ctx);

  if(!SSL_use_certificate_file(ssl, CLIENT_CERTIFICATE, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM)) 
  {
    printf("Error in loading client certificate\n");
    abort();
  }
  else 
  {
    printf("Client certificate loaded succesfully\n");
  }

  if(!SSL_use_PrivateKey_file(ssl, CLIENT_PRIVATE_KEY, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM)) 
  {
    printf("Error in loading client private key\n");
    abort();
  }
  else 
  {
    printf("Client Private Key loaded succesfully\n");
  }

  SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);

  if(SSL_connect(ssl) <= 0) 
  {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    printf("Failed to establish SSL connection\n");
    abort();
  }
  else 
  {
    printf("Succesfully established SSL connection\n");
    ShowCerts(ssl);
  }

  close(server);
  SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
  return 0;
}
```

The error I am facing is that the server can verify the client certificates, but the client cannot verify the server certificates

i.e. on the server side, I get `Verification success, certificate OK` but on the client-side I get the `Verification failed` message

The error message received is

```
139715477161904:error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:s3_clnt.c:1264
```

**Info related to certificates:** both the client, and server certificates have been created using the same CA, which is stored in the /caroot directory. All paths and certificates are valid

Comment: This was tagged as [c++] but there's not a single C++ feature or header in sight. Is `openssl s_client` happy with your server?

Comment: In general it's a good idea to use a working side when debugging the other.  This reduces the problem to 1 instead of 2 unknowns.  There is also `openssl s_server`

Comment: Works for me with properly generated certificates. So I guess the problem is in the certificates you use but don't provide.